# Change path for cached images

Tags: ce-image

My images are on this folder:

```
http://localhost/images/uploads/blog/
```

After i resize them using CE Image, they end up here:

```
http://localhost/cache/images/uploads/blog/
```

Is there any way i can exclude /images/uploads (using the plugin, not with .htaccess)? So that CE Image can save them in:

```
http://localhost/cache/blog/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to play with parameter [hide_relative_path](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#hide_relative_path) and [cache_dir](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#cache_dir). Based on what u use for upload, you can make this like:

```
{news_image}
     {exp:ce_img:single src="{path}{file_name}" cache_dir="/cache/{location}/" hide_relative_path="yes"}
{/news_image}
```

Comment: Thanks, was using either one or another, but not both!